# convert bigint to number of days

Tags: mysql, sql, days, bigint

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS user_registeredon, 
            FROM_UNIXTIME(renewal_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS expiry_date,
            a.agent_id
     FROM ta_agent a,
          ta_subscription s
     WHERE s.agent_id = a.agent_id
```

MY OUTPUT

[image]

I want to show the expiry date in number of days. eg: Expired in 69 days. how to convert bigint to number of days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS user_registeredon, 
        ROUND((renewal_date - date_of_registration)/(60*60*24)) AS expiry_date,
        a.agent_id
 FROM ta_agent a,
      ta_subscription s
 WHERE s.agent_id = a.agent_id
```

Comment: seconds*minut*hours. Unixtime is stored as seconds from Begin of UNIX epoche (01.01.1970)